# Navigate to another stack navigator screen from a view not in the navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

So I've got a view that contains both a stack navigator and a view at the bottom. The view at the bottom serves as a footer. Currently I'm trying to use a reference to the stack navigator but its not working. How do I trigger a screen navigation in the StackNavigator view from the footer view?

[image]

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        /*This is the Stack Navigator*/
        <myNavigator.StackNavigation ref={(c)=>{this._stacky = c}} screenProps={{setNowPlaying:this.setNowPlaying.bind(this), 
        globalState:this.state,
        showFooterPlayer:this.showFooterPlayer.bind(this), 
        playPauseSong:this.playPauseSong.bind(this),
        seekToPosition:this.seekToPosition.bind(this)}}/>

        /*This is the footer section*/
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{console.log(this._stacky); this._stacky.navigation.navigate('Player')}} style={[styles.bottomFooterContainer, {height:this.state.showFooterPlayer?60: 0}]}>
          <Image style={styles.headerImage} source={{uri:this.state.nowPlaying.image}} resizeMode="cover" />
          <View style={styles.playerRight}>
             <Text style={styles.songTitle} ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={1}>{this.state.nowPlaying.title}</Text> 
            {/* <Text style={styles.songTitle}>{counter}</Text> */}
            <View style={styles.controlButtonsContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity><Image style={styles.controlButton} source={require('./app/images/previous.png')} resizeMode="cover" /></TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.playPauseSong}><Image style={styles.controlButton} source={this.state.isPlaying?pauseImage: playImage} resizeMode="cover" /></TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity><Image style={styles.controlButton} source={require('./app/images/next.png')} resizeMode="cover" /></TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: pass navigation as props to your view: `<CusomtView navigation={this.props.navigation} />`, you can use navigation in your custom view now.

Comment: @ShukarullahShah could you please elaborate. Both the stack navigation and the footer are in the same `<View></View>` as can be seen in the code I posted. What I want to do is press a button in the footer to trigger a navigation in the stack navigation. I've added comments to the code so you can see the part with the stack navigator and the part that is the footer